# mysqli::select_db(): Couldn't fetch siteHeader in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\class\siteHeader.php on line 26

Tags: php, mysqli

I keep getting the error eponymous with the title here... I cannot figure out why this is happening. I've spent the past hour or so tyring to get it to work and nadda.

```
<?php
class siteHeader extends siteSetting
{
    public $html;
    public $pid;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
            $this->pid = $_GET['pid'];
            $this->html .= "<body>";
            $this->html .="<div id='site_header'>";
            $this->constructHeader();
            $this->constructMenu();
            $this->html .="</div>";
            $this->html .= "</body>";

    echo $this->html;
    }
    function constructHeader()
    {
        $this->html .= '<h1>'.SITE_NAME.'</h1>';
    }
    function constructMenu()
    {
        parent::select_db('thc_settings');
        $que = parent::query('SELECT * FROM pages');
        $row = $que->fetch_array();
        echo $row[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the parent class with the definition of the select_db() method look like?

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit `SiteSettings` class first. The function that reffered on line 26 tries to fetch "siteHeader" but it doesn't exists on your mysql table.

```
parent::select_db('thc_settings');
```

So, check `siteSettings` class find `select_db` function and edit it to not fetch `siteHeader`